# Arbitrary increasing spectral radius by adding a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

Given matrices $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n},C\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, for all $\epsilon >0$ does there exists some $L\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ such that $\rho(A-LC)=\rho(A)+\epsilon$?

where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of the matrix $A$.

The answer in negative when $C=0$, but i think it is positive in the other case.

My attempt is to write $A$ in a Jordan canonical form and $LC$ in the same basis, then deduce the hypothesis, but i don't know if we can write $LC$ in the same basis since there are rank constraints on $C$ i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since $\lim_{k\to\infty}\rho\left(\frac1kA-C^TC\right)=\rho\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1kA-C^TC\right)=\rho(-C^TC)=\|C\|_2^2>0$, we have $\lim_{k\to\infty}\rho\left(A-kC^TC\right)=+\infty$. Therefore $\rho\left(A-kC^TC\right)=\rho(A)+\epsilon$ for some $k$, by the continuity of $\rho$ and the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Thank you, I understand correctly how you used the IVT, but what is the interest of the first part (Since $\cdots >0$), is it to show that the function $f(k)=\rho(A-kC^{T}C)$ is continuous?

Comment: @pioneer I need $\lim_{k\to\infty}\rho\left(\frac1kA-C^TC\right)>0$ to ensure that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\rho(A-kC^TC)=+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, It is clear now, I think that we can generalize the result as follows:  

Given $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, then:

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists B>0:\rho(A+B)=\rho(A)+\epsilon$$
Is it true?

Comment: @pioneer Your new statement is true I wouldn't call it a generalisation, because the matrix added to $A$ now does not take a special form. Anyway, it's true because you may take $B=kI$ for an appropriate $k\ne0$.